# Maintenance Table, presentation of Data using record details as column headers and extracting only most recent maintenance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried to find a solution to this issue I'm facing but I'm not sure how to advance.
To be honest I am not too sure how to even phrase my question, but please bear with me.

I have a table which is essentially a table which is written into every time an update on a customer record is made, its an odd table but it has been in use for quite awhile and contains over a thousand records. The customer records are not often updated due to the nature of the business.

Now since the table is updated every time an update to the customer record is performed, it is such that each record in this table only contains 4 parts, the customerID, the field which was updated, the details which were updated into the said field, and the date on which the update was performed.
Sample:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| CUSTID            UPDFIELD    UPDDETAILS              UPDDATE    | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 444001001201111   custName    Smith Worlogh           2014-02-01 |
| 444001001201111   discRate    5%                      2014-05-01 |
| 444001001201111   custName    Smith Warlogh           2014-05-07 |
| 444001001201111   custEmail   smithkiw67@yahoo.com    2014-05-10 |
| 444001001201112   custName    Pauline HG Stone        2014-02-01 |
| 444001001201112   discRate    5%                      2014-05-07 |
| 444001001201112   custEmail   sama8kitty@live.co.uk   2014-05-11 |
| 444001001201112   discRate    8%                      2014-05-15 |
| 444001001201113   custName    Jayden Rothschild       2014-05-01 |
| 444001001201113   discRate    8%                      2014-05-07 |
| 444001001201113   custEmail   mr.bombastic@gmail.com  2014-05-11 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From that table I want to present the data in a way where all the details are shown for each customerID and in the last column a date, corresponding to the last update for that particular record is shown. Using the Sample above, I want to present the data like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CUSTID           CUSTOMERNAME       CUSTOMEREMAIL           DISCRATE  LASTUPDATED |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 444001001201111  Smith Warlogh      smithkiw67@yahoo.com    5%        2014-05-10  |
| 444001001201112  Pauline HG Stone   sama8kitty@live.co.uk   8%        2014-05-15  |
| 444001001201113  Jayden Rothschild  mr.bombastic@gmail.com  8%        2014-05-11  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I believe my first step should be to find the most recent update for each particular customer which I managed to do with this simple SELECT statement

```
SELECT MAX(UpdDate) AS LatestUpd,CustID
FROM trackChangeA
GROUP BY CustID;
```

After that I thought I could use the above results in a subquery to extract the latest updates for each field for each respective customer but instead everything is returned.

I am unsure how to proceed from here. Again I did try looking through the SQL section for something similar but all I managed to find was a way to use DISTINCT but trying that didn't change the results much.

I've been trying to try solutions on the sample table in SQL fiddle but so far to no success. Here's the link if it helps: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19fe5/15/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track by using the `max()` aggregate to get the most recent date for each `CustId`.  I'd suggest a few minor changes to get the final result.

First, using your existing query to join the `max(UpdDate)` to your table, then use the windowing function `row_number()` to get the most recent value for each of the `UpdField` values.  So the start of your query will be:

```
select a.CustId, a.UpdField, a.UpdDetails, a.UpdDate, md.maxDate,
  row_number() over(partition by a.CustId, a.UpdField
                    order by a.UpdDate desc) seq
from trackChangeA a
inner join
(
  select max(UpdDate) maxDate, CustId
  from trackChangeA
  group by CustId
) md
  on a.CustId = md.CustId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19fe5/37). This windowing function will create a unique sequenced value for each combination of the `CustId` and the `UpdField`, ordering those values by the `UpdDate`.  From this query, you'll only need those rows where the sequence is 1 or the first row.

Once you've done this, then you can pivot the data easily using an aggregate function with a CASE expression so the final query will be similar to:

```
select CustId,
  CustomerName = max(case when updfield = 'custName' then UpdDetails end),
  CustomerEmail = max(case when updfield = 'custEmail' then UpdDetails end),
  DiscRate = max(case when updfield = 'discRate' then UpdDetails end),
  LastUpdated = MaxDate 
from
(
  select a.CustId, a.UpdField, a.UpdDetails, a.UpdDate, md.maxDate,
    row_number() over(partition by a.CustId, a.UpdField
                      order by a.UpdDate desc) seq
  from trackChangeA a
  inner join
  (
    select max(UpdDate) maxDate, CustId
    from trackChangeA
    group by CustId
  ) md
    on a.CustId = md.CustId
) d
where seq = 1
group by CustId, MaxDate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19fe5/36).

You could also use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result.  The syntax would be similar to:

```
select CustId,
  CustomerName = custName,
  CustomerEmail = custEmail,
  DiscRate = discRate,
  LastUpdated = MaxDate 
from
(
  select a.CustId, a.UpdField, a.UpdDetails, a.UpdDate, md.maxDate,
    row_number() over(partition by a.CustId, a.UpdField
                      order by a.UpdDate desc) seq
  from trackChangeA a
  inner join
  (
    select max(UpdDate) maxDate, CustId
    from trackChangeA
    group by CustId
  ) md
    on a.CustId = md.CustId
) d
pivot
(
  max(UpdDetails)
  for UpdField in (custName, custEmail, discRate)
) piv
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19fe5/39). Both will return the result:

```
|          CUSTID |      CUSTOMERNAME |          CUSTOMEREMAIL | DISCRATE | LASTUPDATED |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------|-------------|
| 444001001201111 |     Smith Warlogh |   smithkiw67@yahoo.com |       5% |  2014-05-10 |
| 444001001201112 |  Pauline HG Stone |  sama8kitty@live.co.uk |       8% |  2014-05-15 |
| 444001001201113 | Jayden Rothschild | mr.bombastic@gmail.com |       8% |  2014-05-11 |
```

Edit: Based on your question whether or not you can use `select distinct` to get the list of columns names for the pivot, the answer is Yes. You can use dynamic SQL to generate the list of names that will be displayed in the final result.  This process creates a query string that will then be executed by SQL Server. The basic syntax will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- generate the list of columns
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(UpdField) 
                    from trackChangeA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- generate the sql string
set @query = N'SELECT CustId,' + @cols + N',  LastUpdated = MaxDate 
            from 
            (
              select a.CustId, a.UpdField, a.UpdDetails, md.maxDate,
                row_number() over(partition by a.CustId, a.UpdField
                                  order by a.UpdDate desc) seq
              from trackChangeA a
              inner join
              (
                select max(UpdDate) maxDate, CustId
                from trackChangeA
                group by CustId
              ) md
                on a.CustId = md.CustId
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(UpdDetails)
                for UpdField in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p 
            where seq = 1'

-- execute the sql string
execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19fe5/43). This will give the same result as the previous version.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer taught me quite a few new things, some of which I do not yet fully understand and will need to read up on. Especially the OVER(partition by).

I'm also wondering if it is possible to instead of static-ly defining the UpdField values in the pivot function, is it possible to maybe use a SELECT DISTINCT statement?

Thank you again for your detailed answer and demo.

Comment: @HexEDSyght Yes you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`, this will be by using dynamic sql to generate the result.  See my edit, I provided you some sample code and a demo to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.CustID,
   (SELECT TOP 1 UpdDetails
    FROM trackChangeA
    WHERE CustID=a.CustID AND UpdField='custName'
    ORDER BY UpdDate DESC
   ) AS custName,
   (SELECT TOP 1 UpdDetails
    FROM trackChangeA
    WHERE CustID=a.CustID AND UpdField='custEmail'
    ORDER BY UpdDate DESC
   ) AS custEmail,
   (SELECT TOP 1 UpdDetails
    FROM trackChangeA
    WHERE CustID=a.CustID AND UpdField='discRate'
    ORDER BY UpdDate DESC
   ) AS discRate,
   MAX(UpdDate) AS LastUpdated
FROM trackChangeA a
GROUP BY a.CustID;
```

The TOP 1 can be substituted with LAST() on some RDBMS, but not on SQL-Server.

Essentially you are getting the CustID list with the last global update date from a grouped by select on the table, while the last values of the 3 update type are fetched by subselects.

Comment: Thanks Frazz. Your answer is very precise and short. I selected bluefeet's answer because to me personally it seems more scale-able.

I do like the simplicity in the statement though and if I can figure out how to remove the static-ly defined UpdField values, I might decide to go with your method. Thanks again for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: You cannot remove that without resorting to PIVOT or CROSSTAB syntax clauses, like the ones bluefeet has shown you. SQL-Server and some other RDBMS do support these types of features. The answer I have given is basically how you implement a static CROSSTAB in standard SQL and works on most all RDBMS... but is static.